# Implement queues in Zeromq

Tags: message-queue, zeromq

I have been playing with RabbitMQ which supports queuing to a broker..

But how do you implement queues in the ZeroMq, When I tried implementing a client and server in Zeromq, I dont know how zeromq implements queue..  So if the client is very fast, and the server is slow( can be done by adjusting sleep time of server) server doesnt seem to get all the messages sent by the client.. Initially I thought probably the server would queue the client requests in some queue, but from my experiments, it doesnt seem to work that way (messages are lost)!!

Any suggestions..

Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ZMQ has ways of dealing with over-full queues (called "high water mark"). When a queue is full, ØMQ automatically blocks senders, or throws away messages, depending on the kind of messaging you are doing (the so-called "pattern")."

Read more about this in the [zmq guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall)